# **Error with st.session_state attribute**

Tags: python, streamlit

I am new to python and streamlit and I am creating a bot to answer based on a vectorstore and i am using Langchain too. This is my part for the streamlit UI code and although I initialize the session state, I'm having an error related to it.

```
if "generated" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["generated"] = []

if "past" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["past"] = []

if "stored_session" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["stored_session"] = [] 


def get_text():
    input_text = st.text_input("You: ", st.session_state.get("input", "Hello, how are you?"), key="input",
                               placeholder="Your Notion bot, ask me anything")
    return input_text

def new_chat()
    save = []
    for i in range(len(st.session_state['generated'])-1, -1, -1):
        save.append("User:" + st.session_state["past"][i])
        save.append("Bot:" + st.session_state["generated"][i])        
    st.session_state["stored_session"].append(save)
    st.session_state["generated"] = []
    st.session_state["past"] = []
    st.session_state["input"] = ""

st.sidebar.button("New Chat", on_click=new_chat)

user_input = get_text()

if user_input:

    result = chain({"question": user_input})
    output = f"Answer: {result['answer']}"
    #output = f"Answer: {result['answer']}\nSources: {result['sources']}"
        
    st.session_state.past.append(user_input)
    st.session_state.generated.append(output)


if st.session_state["generated"]:

    for i in range(len(st.session_state["generated"]) - 1, -1, -1):
        message(st.session_state["past"][i], is_user=True, key=str(i) + "_user")
        message(st.session_state["generated"][i], key=str(i))
```

The error i get is :
`AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "past". Did you forget to initialize it?`
I am running the script in the terminal using streamlit run filename.py
What could be the problem?

Comment: Why did you think that `st.session_state` should have an attribute called `past`? The problem is that it does not have it.

Comment: Did you mean `st.session_state["past"]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes st.session_state["past"] is the one i am talking about , but what do you mean by it does not have it?

Comment: `st.session_state` does not have an attribute called `past`. Therefore `st.session_state.past` raises the exception you have shown.

Comment: But what about this part of code here?
if "past" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["past"] = []

Comment: That doesn't create an attribute, it appears like `st.session_state` is a dictionary and this line inserts an empty list at the key `"past"`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so what can I do in this case?

Comment: Don't use `st.session_state.past` but `st.session_state["past"]`.

Comment: Like this you mean  ```st.session_state["past"].append(user_input)```, if so i have tried but still get that error

Comment: The error traceback should tell you where the error originates from. Maybe it's from some other part of the code you haven't shown here.

Comment: Thank you for you answers, in the other part of code i just load the langchain but this is the error
```\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  \langchain-notion-chat\streamlit.py", line 67, in <module>
    st.session_state["past"].append(user_input)```
```\session_state_proxy.py", line 90, in __getitem__
    return get_session_state()[key]```
```\safe_session_state.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'past'```

Answer (score 2):

just run your python code by

```
streamlit run xxx.py
```